# normalization of data points in order to make them adhere to a specified probability distribution (e.g. Normal)

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, image-processing, threshold, computer-vision

I am doing some preprocessing for a computer vision task. My target is to select a few elements (pixels) containing highest scores according to a metric that I am developing. The values of this metric vary across several images, so that thresholding, even after the usual mean/standard deviation standardization, is leading to overinclusion or overexclusion of pixels. I wonder if it exists a normalization method that makes my point adhere to a specified probability distribution, for example Normal. In that way I could still use tresholding to get always a similar amount of pixels.

thanks!

Comment: If your goal is to select a given amount of pixels with highest scores, why can't you just simply do it? Why bother with thresholding at all?

Comment: @psarka visualization purposes, and to keep everything as nice matrices, and to learn how to do probability distribution transformations from sample data